# css - footer wont stick at the bottom

Tags: css, footer

Im building a website and the footer wont stick at the bottom. Could someone help me with this issue?

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    background-color: #454245;
    bottom: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: post your html and a fiddle please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to provide position as absolute and it will only work when you can provide a wrapper or a parent div with position relative.

Look at this fiddle `[http://jsfiddle.net/tLyC6/]`[1](http://jsfiddle.net/tLyC6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:  **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrqx6/4/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Your content goes here.</p>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Footer content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer,.push{
    background-color:#ccc;
    height: 155px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a sticky footer by setting its `position: fixed` (not `relative`) with `bottom: 0`

```
#footer {
    background-color: #454245;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want footer to stick at the bottom, you can do it with using less code.

```
#footer {
    background-color: #454245;
    height: 200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: Because the want to footer stick at the bottom. and you can do it by using less coding.